# Neodatis object DB / DataNucleus - How are indicies defined?

Tags: java, datanucleus, object-oriented-database

How do I define fields that I know I will be querying on to be indexed using Neodatis Object Database under DataNucleus?

The @Index annotation appears to only apply to ORM for relational databases by my understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the code
http://datanucleus.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/datanucleus/platform/store.neodatis/trunk/src/java/org/datanucleus/store/neodatis/NeoDatisStoreManager.java?revision=9380&view=markup
where you can see "IndexMetaData" being used.

Comment: I see a method getIndexMetaData() which is a method from AbstractMemberMetaData. But I can't easily see what code populates AbstractMemberMetaData to indicate that an index is created or not. I am guessing that this means that @Index is supported to create indexes in neodatis? though the docs suggest that it's only ORM (relational databases) that @Index applies to, and the neodatis specific section left out any mention of indexes that I saw. Thanks for your response, and I appreciate any clarification you can offer.